# Finite bit strings that do not contain '$00$'

Tags: combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers, binary

I am studying for an exam and I am having trouble with this practice question:

In this question, we consider finite bit strings that do not contain $00$. Examples of such bitstrings are $0101010101$ and $11110111$. For any integer $n\geq 2$, let $B_n$ be the number of bitstrings of length $n$ that do not contain $00$.

- Determine $B_2$ and $B_3$.
- Prove that $B_n = B_{n-1} + B_{n-2}$ for each $n\geq 4$.
- For each $n\geq 2$, express $B_n$ in terms of a Fibonacci number.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: How many bit strings are there of length $2$?  Can you write out what they are?

Answer (score 4):

$\textbf{Hint:}$The first question can be answered by simply counting. For the second question note that every bitstring without $00$ ends in either $1$ or in $10$. How many possibilities are there in either case? The third question can be answered by combining the results of the first two questions.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So for the first question, am I thinking of the counting correctly: 2^2-2^1 = 3 and 2^3-2^2 = 4? As for question 2, mind going into more detail? I'm still quite confused.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Suppose we have a bit string of length $n$. Consider the first digit of this bit string:

If the first digit is $1$, i.e. we have $1xxxxxxxxxxxxx\ldots$ as our bit string. How many possibilities are there for the remaining $n-1$ digits?

If the first digit is $0$, what $\mathbf{must}$ the next digit be? What are the possibilities for the remaining $n-2$ digits?

Comment: For the first thing, it must be 0 or 1 following the 1, so we'll have 2^n - 2^n-1 (so as to not count 00). Is my thinking correct?

Comment: Not quite. You are assuming any bit strings will do for the remaining digits; they must follow the same condition that they do not contain $'00'$. You wrote down a symbol for the number of bit strings of length $n$ that do not contain $'00'$ and called it $B_{n}$. Therefore, if we choose the first digit to be $1$, the rest can be any bit string of length $n-1$ following the rules we set; hence, there are $B_{n-1}$ such possibilities. If the first digit is $0$, the next one MUST be $1$. Hence, there are $n-2$ digits free, and therefore $B_{n-2}$ bit strings for the zero case.